# In C, can you have strings in arrays and, if not, is there a workaround

Tags: c

In this code, you type in a number and it tells you whether or not it's prime by returning 0 or 1. It should then print either item 0 or 1 of the array 'prime'. However, I am having problems with this and I don't know how to workaround the list problems. (I'm completely new to C)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int test(int number) { /*1 means prime, 0 means not*/
    int iter;
    int mod;
    if (number == 1) {
        return 0;
    }
    for (iter=2;iter<number-1;iter+=1) {
        if (number % iter == 0){
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
int main(){
    char prime[2] = {'This number isn\'t prime','This number is prime'};
    int userIn;
    printf("Enter an integer to check: ");
    scanf("%d",userIn);
    printf("%c",prime[test(userIn)]);
}
```

Comment: `char` means a single character, and strings are delimited by double-quotes

Comment: The work around is to read the chapter about arrays in your beginner-level C book, then the chapter about strings after that. The code is nonsense.

Comment: Turns out that the problems were just in the scanf with putting 'userIn' no '&userIn' and with the array 'prime' not being multidimensional. Thanks for everyone's help as it's now working!

Answer (score 0):

I have added function declaration and printf.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int primeNumber(int number); //function declaration

int main() {
    int userIn;
    printf("Enter an integer to check: ");
    scanf("%d",&userIn);
    if(primeNumber(userIn) == 0) {
        printf("This number isn\'t prime");
    } else {
        printf("This number is prime");
    }
    return 0;
}

int primeNumber(int number) {
    int iter;
    if (number == 1 || number < 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    for (iter = 2; iter < number - 1; iter += 1) {
        if (number % iter == 0){
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;

}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
bool IsPrime (int number) { // Make your function names more descriptive...
    int iter;
    // int mod; ...and remove superfluous variables

    if (number < 1) {
        return false;
    }

    // There are further possibilities for improvement here...
    for (iter = 2; iter < number - 1; iter += 1) {
        if (number % iter == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    const char* outcomes[2] = { "This number isn't prime", "This number is prime" };
    int input;
    printf("Enter an integer to check: ");
    scanf("%d", &input);   // Note that scanf requires pointer to input! 
    printf("%s", outcomes[IsPrime(input)]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So all negative numbers are prime? That's news to me. If you think it's appropriate to answer with a wad of code, then at least get the bugs out.

Comment: Thanks for your extremely constructive feedback